# Always include right most 6 digits, but allow for more digits if they aren't leading zeroes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may sound like a weird request, but I have to make an excel sheet with EXACTLY the same format as their old sheet. The values in the column in question will be a numeric code. I need to display up to 8 digits, and no less than 6 digits. The code will only be 7 or 8 digits if the first number in the sequence is not zero. If there are 6 digits or less, I need to display 6 digits including leading zeroes. Here is an example:

The data comes in like this:

```
000023547612
000000873901
000031765429
000000000941
000000055701
```

I need those numbers to display as:

```
23547612
873901
31765429
000941
055701
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a SQL statement?

Comment: use LPAD function

Comment: What is the datatype of your source column: string or numeric?

Comment: `select format(number, N'##000000', 'iv')`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia thats MySQL isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length of the string and use `right` to pad it. But GSerg's answer is better.

```
declare @Test table (Number varchar(12))

insert into @Test (Number)
values ('000023547612'),('000000873901'),('000031765429'),('000000000941'),('000000055701')

select Number
  , case when len(convert(varchar(12), convert(int, Number))) <= 6 then right('000000'+convert(varchar(12), convert(int, Number)),6) else convert(varchar(12), convert(int, Number)) end
  , format(convert(int, Number), N'##000000') -- GSerg's Answer
from @Test
```

Returns:

```
Number          Attempt1    Attempt2 (GSerg)
000023547612    23547612    23547612
000000873901    873901      873901
000031765429    31765429    31765429
000000000941    000941      000941
000000055701    055701      055701
```

PS: In future if you provide test data in this format (table variable or temp table) you will make it much easier for people to answer.

Answer (score -2):

[image]You can use

```
SELECT Substring('0078956', Patindex('%[^0 ]%', '0078956' + ' '), Len('0078956') ) AS Trimmed_Leading_0;
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. It pays to check your answer before posting it. "000000000941" still goes to "941"

Comment: What is the datatype of your source column: string or numeric?